send mail with empty from header field
I'd like to send a mail using mailutils on Debian 12, but without or with a empty FROM field. In my Proxmox mail gateway there are sporadic mails without a from field. I've created a rule to replace it, but I can't test it because mailutils forces me to set a from field. It's either being replaced with "None" or "username@hostname".
Does anyone have any ideas?

Are you talking about the "From:" header or the "MAIL FROM" SMTP command? The first one is arbitrary and may be empty (but mail servers may refuse mails without it), but the second one is mandatory to send mail.

I'm talking about the header
